# How to remove duplicates and filter for specific content in XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm an xsl beginner and I've been trying to get this working for a couple days now but I'm having some issues. I've done some research and tried a few different solutions but I can't seem to get it right. Using xsl 1.0 and a specified input, I need to remove duplicates and also be able to filter for specific key words.

Here is the input:

```
<vce>
<document>
    <content name="title">X</content>
    <content name="description">
        <content name="h3">A</content>
        <content name="h3">B</content>
        <content name="h3">C</content>
        <content name="h3">A</content>
        <content name="h3">B</content>
        <content name="h3">C</content>
        <content name="h3">D</content>
        <content name="h3">E</content>
        <content name="h3">F</content>
        <content name="h3">G</content>
    </content>
</document>
</vce>
```

In the description, I can only accept A, B, and C, but also need to make sure there are no duplicates. Therefore my desired output should be:

```
<vce>
<document>
    <content name="title">X</content>
    <content name="description">
        <content name="h3">A</content>
        <content name="h3">B</content>
        <content name="h3">C</content>
    </content>
</document>
</vce>
```

This is what I'm currently working with:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <vce>
    <document>
      <content name="title">
        <xsl:for-each select="//document/content[@name='title']">
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:for-each>
      </content>

      <content name="description">
        <xsl:for-each select="//document/content[@name='h3']">
          <xsl:if test="not(preceding::document[content[@name='h3']/text() = current()/content[@name='h3']/text()])">
            <content name="h3">
              <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </content>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </content>
    </document>
  </vce>
 </xsl:template>
```

Thanks ahead of time for your guys' efforts!

Comment: *I'm an xsl beginner and I've been trying to get this working for a couple days now*...and where is this XSLT trial?

Comment: What version of XSLT?

Comment: I'm working with version 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a lot of your input isn't changing in the output, I'd start with an [identity transform](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying) to copy everything over as-is by default. Then you can add templates to override the identity transform where needed.

You'll also want to use the [Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) of grouping to remove the duplicates.

Your input is super basic, so hopefully this will work with your actual data.

**XML Input**

```
<vce>
    <document>
        <content name="title">X</content>
        <content name="description">
            <content name="h3">A</content>
            <content name="h3">B</content>
            <content name="h3">C</content>
            <content name="h3">A</content>
            <content name="h3">B</content>
            <content name="h3">C</content>
            <content name="h3">D</content>
            <content name="h3">E</content>
            <content name="h3">F</content>
            <content name="h3">G</content>
        </content>
    </document>
</vce>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="desc" match="content[@name='description']/content" use="."/>

  <!--Identity Transform-->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="content[@name='description']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="content[.='A' or .='B' or .='C']
        [count(.|key('desc',.)[1])=1]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<vce>
   <document>
      <content name="title">X</content>
      <content name="description">
         <content name="h3">A</content>
         <content name="h3">B</content>
         <content name="h3">C</content>
      </content>
   </document>
</vce>
```

Here's another version that might make it easier to manage the "allowed" elements.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="allowed" select="'|Step A.|Step B.|Step C.|'"/>

  <xsl:key name="desc" match="content[@name='description']/content" use="."/>

  <!--Identity Transform-->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="content[@name='description']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="content[contains($allowed,concat('|',normalize-space(),'|'))]
        [count(.|key('desc',.)[1])=1]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: How about if the content I was looking for was more complicated than just A, B, and C. For example, if I'm looking for any text that contains the keyword 'step' or a number followed by '.' (i.e. '1.'), will <xsl:for-each select="content[.='A' or .='B' or .='C'] still work?

Comment: @MarkB - Yeah that should still work fine. You may want to use `normalize-space()` instead of just `.` though just so any extraneous spaces don't factor into the comparison. Example: `normalize-space()='Step 1.'` I also added another example that uses an xsl:param to hold what's being compared. That might make it easier to manage. It should be a good start at least.